# Unable to find included file when i run ionic cordova build ios

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Im trying to make a build of a app in IOS using ionic.

i run in terminal `ionic cordova build ios --release --prod`

But im receiving:

> build-release.xcconfig line 28: Unable to find included file
>   "../pods-release.xcconfig"** BUILD FAILED **

I find build-release.xcconfig and in 28 line i find this import:

```
#include "../pods-release.xcconfig"
```

i dont find this archive in my project. How i can generate this archive?

I install cocoapods following this steps:

Navigate to platforms/ios and run:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods

pod setup

pod init

pod install
```

So i run ionic cordova build ios --release --prod and receive the error.

Answer (score 1):

Now, there can be a number of reasons for this error to exist, e.g. the file is, in fact, missing. That is because cordova itself is supposed to handle native plugin installation, you do need to install cocoapods yourself, but not `pod install`.

However, the likely culprit here is XCode's new build system. In layman's terms, what's happened, among other things, is that the default folder structure changed with XCode 10 (released September 17th 2018), screwing up most of how cordova operates.

As is, you have two options:

1. Manually revert to the legacy build system in XCode under File -> Workspace Settings -> Build Settings
2. Run your command with the following flag: `ionic cordova build ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"`

Both of these solutions probably require that you first remove and add the platform. Cordova 5.0 was released where modern build system is supported out of the box, but I'm skeptical of hastily released versions.